# with FastAPI, is it possible to have default path parameters?

Tags: python, fastapi

my question is, how can i get a default value for the path parameter to work?

for the following endpoint:

```
from FastAPI import Path as fPath

@app.get("/users/{code}")
async def get_user(code: str = fPath("hellomotto", regex=r'hello.*')):
    return {"code": code}
```

now, if i visit `localhost:666/users/helloworld` it will give me a good response:

```
{"code": "helloworld"}
```

however, if i try to go to `localhost:666/users/`,  it will give me a response of `{ "detail": "Not Found" }`

is there a way for it to instead return `{"code": "hellomotto"}` as a default in case the user does not type something like `localhost:666/users/hellomotto`

of course i can just have an endpoint for `/users/` but figured i could set a default...

edit:  also tried `default="hellomoto"`
edit2: when i try with query parameters it does resort to the default value...

Comment: never posted this kind of answer but bro are you the devil? change the port from 666 lol.

Comment: @GeorgeImerlishvili haha i just use consecutive numbers on dev stuff..so not the devil, but i am part georgian ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost:666/users/` matches with `/users/` only, but it will never match `/users/{something}`. That's why FastAPI is returning 404.

However, getting a user by default in that way, doesn't sound to me like a good API design. Usually, a GET `/something/` will return a list of `something`, instead of a specific default element.

What you can do is something like this:

```py
def _get_user(code: str):
    return {"code": code}

@app.get("/users/default")
async def get_user_by_default():
    return _get_user("hellomotto")

@app.get("/users/{code}")
async def get_user_by_code(code: str = Path(..., regex=r'hello.*')):
    return _get_user(code)
```

If you still want to do it with a missing `code` path parameter, you could use `/users/` instead of `/users/default` but I still think it's not a good idea as it's not explicit enough. Besides that, something like that should help to manage that default use case.